# Decimal data type is stripping trailing zero's when they are needed to display

Tags: c#, string, types, decimal

A web app I'm working on (another dev wrote it) has a decimal variable that is dropping two zero's after the decimal.  It does not drop the trailing 2 digits if they contain a number > 0 or a combination of.  The value is coming from a text file.

Example text value is: `261.00`

Example decimal variable (TotalDue) is: `261`

During debug when I hover over the "TotalDue" (in sample code below) the value displays as 261 and when I expand the debugger it reads "261M":

```
decimal TotalDue = Convert.ToDecimal(InputRow.Substring(260, 12));
```

I have tried bringing it in as a string (but initially it still reads as "261" instead of 261.00) and then converting it in various ways as follows.  Nothing is working!

```
string TotalDue = InputRow.Substring(260, 12);

strTotalDue = String.Format("{0:F2}", TotalDue);

strTotalDue = String.Format("{0:N2}", TotalDue);

strTotalDue = String.Format(TotalDue, "0.00");

strTotalDue = TotalDue.ToString("G29");  

strTotalDue = String.Format("{0:0.00}", TotalDue);

strTotalDue = TotalDue.ToString("N2");//used this one with decimal data type
```

What am I missing?  Does it matter where the text file data originated?  It started in an Access database.

**UPDATE:** Today (12/1/15) I realized I never marked an answer because I ended up scrapping the original code and rewriting it in C#.net. I will mark Cole Campbell's answer correct because his remarks *("construct the Decimal in a way that provides it with sufficient data regarding the precision of the input.")* are what prompted me to come up with the solution I did which was to manipulate the incoming data. I did so in a method  - only showing the part that matters (AmtDue) below.  Reminder the incoming data was in the format of "261.00" (e.g. AmtDue = 261.00):

```
string AmtDue = Convert.ToString(AmountDue).Replace(".", "");           
string finalstring =  ("0000000000" + AmtDue).Substring(AmtDue.Length);
```

Comment: Its tough without knowing the pipeline that this is going through - could you show some code context? Otherwise, I would just suggest string.Format - but you've tried that already.

Comment: As others have mentioned in the (rightfully) correct answers; you want to use the "D2" string format.  "N2" pads to the LEFT of the decimal place.

Comment: D2 is not working, guys.

Comment: See answer of Cole Campbell, it is really interesting!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The reason your first example is dropping the zeroes likely has to do with how you're creating the `Decimal` instance.  `Decimal` contains a scaling factor which influences how `ToString()` works, and this scaling factor is set differently based on how the `Decimal` is constructed.

This code:

```
var d1 = Decimal.Parse("261.00");
var d2 = new Decimal(261.00);
var d3 = 261.00m;
Console.WriteLine(d1);
Console.WriteLine(d2);
Console.WriteLine(d3);
```

Produces these results:

```
261.00
261
261.00
```

If you want to preserve the trailing zeroes, construct the `Decimal` in a way that provides it with sufficient data regarding the precision of the input.

Remember that, as noted by other answers, the string provided by the debugger is not necessarily the same as the string produced by `ToString()`.

Comment: Cole this was very enlightening and well written but it still didn't solve my problem...but I'm still playing with it...just wanted to say thank you for taking the time to explain!

Comment: Very interesting.  It only applies to `.ToString()` without any type formatting (as used for implicit conversions), but it's definitely not the behavior I would expect.

Answer (score 20):

If you want two decimal places you can use the proper [`ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ebe5aks.aspx):

```
string formatted = TotalDue.ToString("0.00");
```

[**> Demo <**](http://ideone.com/zckykf)

[**Standard Numeric Format Strings**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

(by the way, `ToString("D2")` doesn't  work)

Comment: LOL.. 10 upvotes, and then you figured out that this will not work))

Comment: @SergeyS: Yes, i was very suprised that nobody has remembered it. I've checked it just for fun and thought that Ideone was the reason(no other IDE available). But however, `"0.00"` works.

Comment: OP has already tried one correct version:  String.Format("{0:0.00}", TotalDue); but it is not working for him. It means that he has another problem (not formatting)

Comment: Answer of Cole Campbell is really interesting! Decimal.ToString really behaves very differently depending on how decimal was initialized.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I am trying the same thing, but i am having `TotalDue ?` a nullable decimal variable. how can i achieve this ?

Comment: @Rohaan: you have to use the `Value` property of `Nullable<decimal>`: `string formatted = TotalDue.Value.ToString("0.00")`. But note that this causes an exception if the value is `null`. Then you can check it first: `string formatted = "0.00"; if(TotalDue.HasValue) formatted = TotalDue.Value.ToString("0.00");`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: As i am using class (DTO) with this field `TotalDue?`, i need to convert this formatted string back to `decimal?` which again removing the trailing zeros :(

Comment: @Rohaan: a `Decimal` or `Decimal?` just stores a value, it has no formatting. You can format a decimal in a string only.

Answer (score 5):

The number you see in the debugger is not connected to how it actually displays in any way.  `261M` is correct - It's a value of "261", stored in decimal ("M" = "Money" = decimal) format.

Try the numeric formatting codes [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).  "F2" is what you want.

Comment: D2 is not working. You need to try and ONLY after that answer.

Comment: @SergeyS - You're right.  That's what I get for just going based on a quick check of the documentation and memory.  Changed it to F2.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure you can google, and have likely come across this link, but here it is for reference:

[String Formatting Doubles](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/)

It appears as if you've already tried `strTotalDue = String.Format("{0:0.00}", TotalDue);` so I'm not sure what else is going wrong.

Without more context however we won't know how to solve this issue.

Comment: Everyone's comments are helpful THANK YOU ! I can get the samples to work in console but not in the application.  Either the problem is somewhere else in the code which I can't yet determine.  The line of code that I showed is the first point of entry that the external text file comes in at. No matter what data type I use, var, string, decimal the text comes in as 261M.

Comment: If the raw data from access is coming in as 261M you need to either strip the M off at your presentation layer and format it then or format the string in access. Although I suspect the m on the end of your value is included for formatting purposes, see Cole Campbells' answer. Make sure you accept his answer if it works!

Comment: @Doreen - As per my answer, looking at "261M" in the debugger is perfectly normal.  But if the data you're reading in is a **string** that says "261M", then that's a data problem.  Can you look at the raw data and see what it looks like there?

Comment: Well I have since learned that the TotalDue variable is used in an external class (written in vb), and is cast as a float like this: