# Stop Automatic Insignificant Decimal Truncating of Double

Tags: c#, formatting, double, number-formatting

I have a double I want to store exactly as is without any of the following formatting:

Example 1: `double a = 12.`
Gets formatted to: `12`

Example 2: `double b = 50.0`
Gets formatted to: `50`

Example 3: `double c = 88.0000000000`
Gets formatted to: `88`

Is that possible (with some "magical" C# feature), or will I have to store it as a string like any other language? I saw `Decimal` has lots of options for formatting numbers but none of the ones I've tried so far get it quite the way I want it (only close).

I'm building a GUI calculator app for educational purposes and want to make sure I'm doing things in the best *C#* way (as I'm doing this project to familiarize myself with the language).

Thank you.

EDIT:  Example: Double is set to 52.000
The user clicks a button in the application that appends
the 52.000 with a 1. New number: 52.0001
Those decimals that were once insignificant now have meaning
because if the zeros from 52.000 got taken away earlier then
this number would be 52.1. Which is a completely different
number from 52.0001. Hence why the zeros do matter in this
situation.

Comment: Always store as a double, format it however you want when its time to format.  Unless you mean to say these numbers should **never** need or have decimal places (i.e they are _integers_)?

Comment: I want these numbers to keep their decimal places so they can be correctly appended to at a later point by my application.

Comment: OK, so your doubles are formatting and you want it to **not** format?

Comment: What if its `23.5`? `23.12345`?

Comment: @Halp: "I want these numbers to keep their decimal places" the values don't *have* decimal places. The value in `double c = 88.0000000000;` is *exactly* the same as the value in `double d = 88;` - they're bitwise equivalent.

Comment: Correct. I want them to stay exactly as I set them, regardless if at this specific point in the application, they are insignificant digits.

Comment: @Halp "correctly appended to" - what type of operation you are looking for? Any math operation on values of any numeric types will wipe trailing zeros... Can you please give a real example of what you are looking for (maybe it should be another Q which is not about specifying trailing zeros)

Comment: There's no value in retaining 0s the way you want them to for computational purposes. Can you specify why you want to keep the formatting?

Comment: `Decimal` does exactly what he wants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't as `double` does not store insignificant digits.

Your options:

- use appropriate format if you just need to print zeros
- switch to `decimal` that preserves the zeros (be careful constructing it so - [Decimal data type is stripping trailing zero's when they are needed to display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769938/decimal-data-type-is-stripping-trailing-zeros-when-they-are-needed-to-display)).
- keep values as strings for display purposes and convert to numerical types when you want to do computations. Based on the edit this is the option you are looking for as you are building calculator - indeed text input should stay as text till user finally decides that input is complete.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `decimal` and don't want to convert to/from string, you may find this helpful:

```
public static int Scale(this Decimal d) => (Decimal.GetBits(d)[3] >>16) & 31;
```